# ¿Como puedo hacer que un JFrame en Java se cierre solo al cabo de unos segundos?

Tags: java, java-swing

En java necesito que  determinado formulario (el mini teclado que he creado, visualizar la imagen) se cierre solo al cabo de unos segundos sólito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que se cierre solo aunque lo siga uno usando? ¿O al dejar de usarlo por cierto tiempo?

Comment: Bienvenido por favor revisa [ask] y modifica tu pregunta, agrega lo que estas realizando, cual es el error? , saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría así:

Calse padre:

```
package com.stackoverflow.es.question363473;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author Ruslan Lopez Carro
 */
abstract class AutoDisposable extends JFrame {

    public AutoDisposable() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

}
```

Clase hija:

```
package com.stackoverflow.es.question363473;

/**
 *
 * @author Ruslan Lopez Carro
 */
public class Autocerrable extends AutoDisposable{

    /**
     * Creates new form Autocerrable
     */
    public Autocerrable() {
        super();
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Bienvenido agente 007, Tu misión es infiltrate en la comunidad C# y capturar a su líder. Este mensaje se autodestruirá en dos segundos");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(85, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(273, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Autocerrable.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Autocerrable.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Autocerrable.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Autocerrable.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Autocerrable().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Nota que el primer parámetro del constructor de `java.swing.Timer` es en milisegundos.

Lo segundo a notar es que estoy llamando explícitamente al constructor de AutoDisposable mediante `super()`, pues es allí donde iniciará nuestro timer.

La desición de ponerlo aparte y no como parte de tu mismo código se debe a un principio de diseño llamado *Single Responsability*, que forma parte de los principios SOLID; una ventaja adicional de esta diseño es que podemos reusarlo tantas veces como queramos.