# Java: ¿Cómo corregir el error Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type?

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8, netbeans-11.3

Hoy probando a responder [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363473/como-puedo-hacer-que-un-jframe-en-java-se-cierre-solo-al-cabo-de-unos-segundos/363480#363480) en este sitio logré producir un error en el [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) en un proyecto de tipo [maven](/questions/tagged/maven).

El error dice así:

> --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ respuestas-stackoverflow --- Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: javax.swing.Timer.<init>
    at com.stackoverflow.es.question363473.AutoDisposable.<init>(AutoDisposable.java:20)
    at com.stackoverflow.es.question363473.Autocerrable.<init>(Autocerrable.java:18)
    at com.stackoverflow.es.question363473.Autocerrable$1.run(Autocerrable.java:87)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:704)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

El error se produjo al tratar de modernizar el código y remplazar una clase interna anónima por un lambda, en concreto:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(2000,
        new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                dispose();
            }
        }
);
```

por

```
  Timer timer = new Timer(2000,()->dispose());
```

e inmediatamente darle click derecho y run file

lo cual ejecuta al comando

```
cd C:\Users\RuslanLopez\Documents\CoolBeansProjects\respuestas-stackoverflow; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-13.0.1.9-openj9" cmd /c "\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-11.3\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.stackoverflow.es.question363473.Autocerrable\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-13.0.1.9-openj9\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-11.3\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec"
```

Answer (score 2):

Según revisé en el sitio en inglés parte del problema viene de la opción de compilar al guardar de netbeans, así que le hice un clean-build mediante el botón y me apareció:

> COMPILATION ERROR :
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------- com/stackoverflow/es/question363473/AutoDisposable.java:[28,28]
>
> incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression

Y lo que pasa es que **no le estaba pasando ningún parámetro al lambda**, porque realmente dentro no lo estaba usando, y el mismo **netbeans no me marcaba ningún error** al respecto.

Al darle click derecho y run file aparece el mensaje de error

> --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ respuestas-stackoverflow --- Error: Could not find or load main class
> com.stackoverflow.es.question363473.Autocerrable Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.stackoverflow.es.question363473.Autocerrable Command execution
> failed.

```
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Esto nos indica la causa de este error tan raro...

Como ntbeans está compilando por nosotros al llamar mediante run file al comando

```
mvn exec-maven-plugin:exec
```

no se realiza el proceso de compilación mediante

```
mvn compile
```

porque las clases ya se remplazaron.

Así es que listo, en resúmen tras modificar a

```
(evt)->dispose()
```

y hacer un maven clean build todo funciona de maravilla, mi consejo es:

- **desactivar la opción compilar al guardar** para asegurarnos de que siempre compilemos absolutamente todo (especialmente si se trata de un proyecto maven multimódulo)